# How to Keep public Interface inside the class in proguard in android

Tags: android, android-proguard

I have a class AB in android application . This class has one public interface INF.
When i try to do a release build with proguard enabled , It says that

error: cannot find symbol class INF

In my proguard.cfg file i have added the following lines:

```
-keep public interface com.some.somemore.AB$INF {*;}
-keep class com.some.somemore.AB {*;}
```

Please help why this error is coming.

```
public class AB {

public interface INF {
    public void Ready();
    public void Error(int error);
    public void Click();
    public void Complete();
    public void Dismiss();
}
```

}

Here are the Crash Logs

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               Process: com.sliq.android.sliq, PID: 14828
                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sliq.android.sliq/org.nexage.sourcekit.vast.activity.VASTActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.nexage.sourcekit.vast.a.e.a()' on a null object reference
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2314)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2388)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
                                                Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.nexage.sourcekit.vast.a.e.a()' on a null object reference
                                                   at org.nexage.sourcekit.vast.activity.VASTActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5953)
                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1128)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2267)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2388) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292) 
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
```

I am using this open source project https://github.com/nexage/sourcekit-vast-android  as a module in my studio project . Its Crashing inside the open source project called VAST. 
I have added VAST as a module dependency inside my studio project. I have enabled proguard for my studio project as well as the VAST module .
Here is the proguard.config file i am using for VAST module:

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-dontpreverify
-dontshrink
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-keep class org.nexage.sourcekit.vast.VASTPlayer {*;}
-keep interface org.nexage.sourcekit.vast.VASTPlayerListener {*;}
-keep class org.nexage.sourcekit.vast.model.** {*;}
-keep class org.nexage.sourcekit.vast.processor.** {*;}
-keep class org.nexage.sourcekit.vast.activity.** {*;}
-keep class org.nexage.sourcekit.util.** {*;}
```

Comment: Post your class and interface code

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation should looks like below:

```
import com.my.packagename.AB;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements AB.TestInterface {

 // other stuff

@Override
public void Ready() {

}

@Override
public void Error(int error) {

}

@Override
public void Click() {

}

@Override
public void Complete() {

}

@Override
public void Dismiss() {

}

}
```

You need to import parent class, hope this will help you.

Comment: you mean the AB class needs to be imported in the activity class.
If so , then i have already imported it . I am getting this error only with proguard enabled . If i disable it . It works

Comment: @PardeepKumar, create separate interface instead of inside class.

Comment: I can try that .I just want to understand whats wrong with this.

Comment: i added the interface separately. I am able to generate the APK. But it crashes . But Debug build runs successfully. Because i do not enable proguard in debug build.

Comment: @PardeepKumar, can you have logcat of crash ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
-keepclassmembers class com.some.somemore.AB { *; }
```

Hope it helps